# Proving statement with Gauss's reciprocity law

Tags: number-theory

> State Gauss' reciprocity law for two distinct odd primes $p$ and $q$.
>   Hence, given an odd prime $p$, prove carefully that the following
>   statements are equivalent:
>
> - $p\neq5$ and there is an intenger $k$ such that $p$ divides $5-k^2$;
> - $p$ is congruent to $\pm1\mod{5}$.

[(Image that replaced text).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/902Rt.png)

I am asked to solve the above question. I have got the Gauss's reciprocity law below.

> For distinct odd primes $p$ and $q$, the theorem states:
>   $$\operatorname{Leg}(q,p)=\begin{cases}\operatorname{Leg}(p,q)&\text{if
> > $p\equiv1$ or $q\equiv1\mod4$},\\-\operatorname{Leg}(p,q)&\text{if
> > $p\equiv-1$ and $q\equiv-1\mod4$}.\end{cases}$$

[(Image that replaced text).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gx3E.png)

I am stuck when I try to do the second bit. Can anyone give me some hints on how to start with the first statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first statement is telling you that there is an integer $k$ such that $p|5-k^2$, this is equivalent to say that there is a $k$ such that $k^2\equiv 5\mod p$, i.e. is equivalent to say that $5$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$, i.e. equivalent to $Leg(5,p)=1$.

So, what you are trying to prove is $Leg(5,p)=1\iff p\equiv \pm 1\mod 5$. You should prove this using quadratic reciprocity. Do you see how?